# implement imapbuilder in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, object, tags

I have created a web page using cakephp. Now I feel like my boring map on the main page is killing it. I bought imapbuilder which lets you do flash effects on images, however I don't seem to be able to get the code working.

Here is the code I pasted in my home page, but it won't load. All I see is a blank square.

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" 
    codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,115,0" 
    width="800" height="747" align="middle">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<param name="movie" value="imapbuilder/loader.swf" />
<param name="base" value="imapbuilder/" />
<param name="flashvars" value="datasource=urlife_map.xml" />
<param name="loop" value="false" />
<param name="menu" value="true" />
<param name="quality" value="best" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
<embed src="imapbuilder/loader.swf" base="imapbuilder/"   flashvars="datasource=urlife_map.xml" loop="false" menu="true" quality="best"    wmode="transparent" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="800" height="747" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"         pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></embed>
</object>
```

This same code I pasted into a separate file and it worked. I kept the folder imapbuilder on the same directory as the home page file.

Does anyone have an idea why this won't load and work on my website?

Answer (score 0):

Files can only be accessed if they are located inside the webroot directory of your app using a standard CakePHP setup.

I suggest you move the imapbuilder folder to the webroot folder and also append all references to it with a / (e.g. /imapbuilder/loader.swf instead of just imapbuilder/loader.swf).

Comment: @allegjdm93 Can you show us your current page with the embed and object tag please?

Answer (score 0):

I think an easier solution for you is to use iMapBuilder.net -- which is the online version of iMapbuilder.  The map will then be remotely hosted on their server, and all you need to do is copy and paste their code so that no file copying / directory issues.

I have used imapbuilder.net on few CMS based sites, e.g. dotnetnuke and wordpress. And the online based map solution is a lot easier than their Windows version, at least for CMS based sites.